# tr output to new lines

Tags: bash, shell, tr, character-replacement

I am trying to remove all non-alphanumeric from a text file with the following command:

```
cat textfile.txt | tr -cd [:alnum:] > textfile_alnum.txt
```

This works, except that now the output within `textfile_alnum.txt` is all on the same line. How can I maintain each string on a separate line?

Comment: Whitespace is by definition not alphanumeric.

Answer (score 5):

If you want new lines from the original file to be preserved, use the following:

```
tr -cd [:alnum:]'\n'
```

This adds the new line character (`\n`) to the set of characters that you want to keep.